# Rails: How to model confirmable Friendship relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So a `user` could send a request of becoming friends to another, and after being confirmed, the relationship is valid?

I think it would be 
`Friendship creator_id:user_id, receiver_id:user_id, confirmed:boolean`, and then restrict the `confirmed` to the `receiver` only.

But that's as far as I can get.

Is there any code that I can refer to? or any gem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.  This gem might be useful for inspiration at least. https://github.com/jrmyward/acts_as_friendable